# Wyse 3040 instalation

Tags: boot, usb, ssd

I'd like to install Ubuntu server on my Wyse 3040. The server install image on a USB stick asks me the first couple of questions, then fails to find the on-board 8GB flash drive and cannot install. How can I help it find the drive?
I tried running the desktop install image on the USB stick, it finds one partition on the flash drive which has a format it does not like. Before I can try re-partitioning it, the desktop version of Ubuntu always freezes up after a few minutes. Tried re-booting a few times, freezes up (cursor stops responding to mouse, tasks do not complete) every time.
I see the Wyse 3040 is "certified pre-installed" but apparently that only means it can come that way from Dell.
I see a patch for the Wyse 3040 at (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2017-October/087627.html) but how do I apply this to my installation kit?

Answer (score 1):

On another thread here, someone suggested using an alternate installation, and it worked! I have Ubuntu working on my Wyse 3040 thin client!
The installation image that I got from the main download page was named:
Ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
This installation kit failed to find any block devices to install onto on two different systems (the Wyse and a Mini PC). Pawing around in the alternate installations page I eventually found one named:
Ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso
This installation kit worked perfectly and found all the block devices on the systems that the -live- one could not find.